# Jquery history cookie for tab slider?

Tags: jquery, cookies, tabs, history, slide

I'm trying to get a cookie to remember the last position of a tabbed slider...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".propgnav" ).tabs({
        cookie: {

            expires: 1
        }
    });
});
```

The above code kinda works....but it only remembers the initial tab that is selected. For example, if I click on another tab after the initial tab and then press back in the browser, the initial tab will still be selected.. :S

I'm using tabs that control a slider: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html

And the tab navigation uses hashes...if that makes a difference? I'm really confused with how to get this to work. Does anyone know how I could create a simple cookie that remembers the last tab selected when you press back in the browser/refresh page?

```
<ul class="propgnav">
           <li><a href="#propg1">1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#propg2">2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#propg3">3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#propg4">4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#propg5">5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Neither use hash navigation as far as i can see. And jqueryu tabs changes the tab position on click, so it shouldnt change. So do you want it to remember a history of previous tabs, and then go back in history? Then it would be better to disable the cookie use, or at least override it by using hashtags, and then setting hte tab from that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the URL (hash navigation as mentioned by @marcojohannesen) when the user clicks the tab - simply assigning the cookie isn't going to help you. When the browser goes back - no ready events are fired.